# Definitive way to stop scrolling in textarea/input fields

Tags: cordova

I have a PhoneGap project, which runs on iOS and and Android. I have a problem on both these platforms in which if I cursor in a text field (on my Eee Pad Transformer) the whole page scrolls.

I have put in a SetTimeout to scroll(0,0) every millisecond, but this results in the page flickering page to 0,0 every time it scrolls. Is it possible to stop this scrolling entirely?

All the best

Garry

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. it may help you

```
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { 
     if(device.platform == "iPhone" && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "textarea"){
         //this condition is for iPhone 3 - to enable default textarea scrolling
         return;
    }
      e.preventDefault();
     });
```